# sql server report server eliminar condicion si es null

Tags: sql-server

Hola estoy intentando hacer un reporte donde tome un dato o otra dependiendo si es nulo o no

Por ejemplo tengo 2 campos OrdenCompra y Fecha y quiero que si Orden de compra es Null entonces solo busque por Fehca y si fecha es null solo por OrdenCompra pero no se como hacerlo :(

Lo que me hace es
**WHERE IdOrdenCompra = NULL AND Fecha = 'una fecha'**

y lo que quiero es
**WHERE Fecha = 'una fecha'**

Cree mis 2 parametros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y los filtros los puse asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has intentado poner en la expresión ambas condiciones y compararlos simplemente con un TRUE?

Comment: En sql server no se puede dar igual a null. Se utiliza is Null. `Where idCompra is null And ....` [Sql Server Is null](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: @Luis Cazares hola eso como es?